# Multiplying Block Matrices in Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, machine-learning, regression

Hi Everyone I am python newbie
I have to implement lasso L1 regression for a class assignment. This involves solving a quadratic equation involving block matrices.

```
minimize x^t * H * x  + f^t * x 
where x > 0
```

Where H is a 2 X 2 block matrix with each element being a k dimensional matrix  and x and f being a 2 X 1 vectors each element being a k dimension vector.

I was thinking of using ndarrays.

Such that :

```
  np.shape(H) = (2, 2, k, k)
  np.shape(x) = (2, k)
```

But I figured out that np.dot(X, H) doesn't work here. 
Is there an easy way to solve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I am convinced that converting to matrices will lead to more efficient computations. Stating that, if you consider your 2k x 2k matrix being a 2 x 2 matrix, then you operate in a tensor product of vector spaces, and have to use `tensordot` instead of `dot`.

Let give it a try, with k=5 for example:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> k = 5
```

Define our matrix `a` and vector `x`

```
>>> a = np.arange(1.*2*2*k*k).reshape(2,2,k,k)
>>> x = np.arange(1.*2*k).reshape(2,k)
>>> x
array([[ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.],
       [ 5.,  6.,  7.,  8.,  9.]])
```

now we can multipy our tensors. Be sure to choose right axes, I didn't tested following formula explicetely, and there might be an error

```
>>> result = np.tensordot(a,x,([1,3],[0,1]))
>>> result
array([[  985.,  1210.,  1435.,  1660.,  1885.],
       [ 3235.,  3460.,  3685.,  3910.,  4135.]])
>>> np.shape(result)
(2, 5)
```

Answer (score 1):

`np.einsum` gives good control over which axes are summed.

```
np.einsum('ijkl,jk',H,x)
```

is one possible (generalized) dot product, (2,4) (first and last dim of H)

```
np.einsum('ijkl,jl',H,x)
```

is another.  You need to be explicit - which dimensions of `x` go with which of `H`.